# Regex Php convert brackets and braces to links like StackOverflow Reddit

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

I'm trying to parse some markup posted by a user in a textbox stored in a mysql database into a link, similar to Reddit's and StackOverflow's style of using:

```
 [foo](http://foo.com) = <a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>
```

So far I've come up with this:

```
 if (stristr($text, '[') == TRUE && stristr($text, '](') == TRUE && 
     stristr($text, ')') == TRUE && strpos($text, '[') == 0) {
      $text = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, ']'));
      $href_start = strpos($text, '(');
      $href = substr($title, $href_start, strpos($text, ')'));
      $text_array = array('[', ']'); $href_array = array('(', ')');
      $href = str_replace($href_array, '', $href);
      $text_string = str_replace($text_array, '', $text_string);
      $text = '<a href="' . $href . '">' . $text_string . '</a>';
 }
```

which works, but only when the comment starts with the link, and not when the link appears in a midst of text. I also need to grab a certain amount of text from the string that is in the brackets for text titles that need to be displayed, so sometimes I would write the last string like this:

```
$title = '<a href="' . $href . '">' . substr($text, 0, 80) . '</a>';
```

So bonus points if someone can tell me how to grab a variable amount of text while performing this string operation. I know about PHP Markdown, but I thought it would be overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = <<<EOS
some text [foo](http://foo.com) and
more text [bar](http://bar.com) and then
a [really looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo00000000000000000ooong description](http://foobar.com)
EOS;


$string = preg_replace_callback(
  '~\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)~',
  function ($m) {
    return '<a href="'.$m[2].'">'.substr($m[1],0,80).'</a>';
  },
  $string
);

echo $string;
```

**output:**

```
some text <a href="http://foo.com">foo</a> and
more text <a href="http://bar.com">bar</a> and then
a <a href="http://foobar.com">really looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo00000000000000000ooong de</a>
```

**edit:**

I suppose you don't *need* to use `preg_replace_callback` for this - can just use `preg_replace` instead, but I like the former better because the regex is a little cleaner and you can have a little more control over building your link. But here's the `preg_replace` version:

```
$string = preg_replace(
  '~\[([^\]]{1,80})[^\]]*\]\(([^)]+)\)~',
  '<a href="$2">$1</a>',
  $string
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex:

```
\[(.{1,80}).*?\]\((.+?)\)
```

And replace it with:

```
<a href="$2">$1</a>
```

You can use `$1` for title, by splitting it by a `' '` or have it as it is.

Code:

```
<?php
$string = '[foo](http://nettpals.in)';
$pattern = '/\[(.{1,80}).*?\]\((.+?)\)/';
$replacement = '<a href="$2">$1</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/xiAT6w

Comment: @AmitJoki It works, but I'm confused as to how you implement the last part of substituting $1 for the length using preg_relace: $text = preg_replace('#\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)#', '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $text);

Comment: @AmitJoki one problem with this is that it does not account for him wanting to cut the link text to max 80 chars...

Comment: @AmitJoki Yeah, what he^^ said. How can I only make a max output of 80 characters or whatever amount of characters? It's ok if you don't know.

Comment: @AmitJoki not quite.. try it with a string longer than 80 chars!

Comment: @CrayonViolent Just noticed it. I wish I could give you both checkmarks, but you did get the bonus.

Comment: @AmitJoki also, "g" is not a valid modifier with `preg_replace`. You should have gotten a warning level error if your settings were turned on for it. By default, `preg_replace` already does global search and replace, and there's an optional 4th arg to limit it

Comment: @user3423909, check out my answer now. Now it does what you wnat

Comment: @AmitJoki man you must hate me, but if i may make one more suggestion.. that `.+?` you added to cover if more than 80, I suggest you change that to `.*?` so that it looks for 0 or more instead of requiring at least 1. And then you should change `{0,80}` to `{1,80}` so the 1 is required there instead since that's where you're actually capturing for `$1`

Comment: No troubles mate, you just helped me in answering correctly